# My ScrollView is not working properly in the Kivy GUI App. in .py file

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to implement my ScrollView with StackLayout in kivy by code in .py file (without the use of .kv file or kv string) but it does not work properly. I has been done all the things which I know to implement the ScrollView in the code in kivy but in spite of that I have an issue in the ScrollView and that is that I am able to Scroll the Screen but it does not Stable at one place and it gets back to upward again when I am stopping the scroll from the mouse.

Moreover it does not show any of the error from which I will get the hint that why it is happening and what is the solution of it.

I am sharing some pictures of the problem that will help you to understand it:

[image1: it is initial state where I want to start scrolling downward by the help of mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4JQx.png)

[image2: this screenshot is taken in between of scrolling the screen downward from the mouse when I am stop scrolling downward and I want to remain at the place where it is but it can't be stable there it will go again to it's initial state from where we started the scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okMKp.png)

The whole source code is here:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivymd.uix.fitimage import FitImage
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.uix.widget import MDWidget
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
# Set the Window Size
Window.size=(1280,800)

class mainHeading(MDWidget,Widget):
    pass


class Elevation(RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior,MDCard):
    pass


class FirstWin(RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior,Screen,mainHeading):
    textReference=[]
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(FirstWin,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        main_widget=BoxLayout(size_hint=(1,1),pos_hint={'x':0,'top':0.9})
        scrollbar=ScrollView(size_hint_y=0.9,pos_hint={'x':0,'top':0.940},do_scroll_x=False,do_scroll_y=True)
        secondary_widget=StackLayout(size_hint=(1,0.99),height=main_widget.height,spacing=50,padding=20)
        secondary_widget.bind(minimum_height=self.setter('height'))
        for i in range(0,21):
            mycard=Elevation(
                elevation=15,
                size_hint =(0.2,0.4),
                orientation='vertical',
                radius= [36, ],
                ripple_behavior=True,
                focus_behavior=True

            )
            mycard.bind(size=self.adjust_sizes)
            image = FitImage(radius=[36,36,0,0],size_hint_y=3, size_hint_x=1,orientation="vertical")
            imagebutton = Button(background_normal="D:/Study/Python/Kivy/images/1.jpg",
                                 background_down="D:/Study/Python/Kivy/images/1.jpg",
                                 size_hint_y=550.0,
                                 size_hint_x=1,
                                 pos_hint={'x': 0, 'y': 0}
                                 )
            imagebutton.bind(on_release=lambda x:self.say_hellow())
            texture_part = MDFloatLayout( md_bg_color=(46 / 255, 8 / 255, 211 / 255, .5),
                                         radius=[0, 0, 36, 36])
            main_text = Button(
                text="Tea and Coffee",
                halign="left",
                bold=True,
                pos_hint={'center_x': 0.4, 'top':1.2},
                size_hint=(1, None),
                height=mycard.height,
                font_size=mycard.width /6,
                background_normal='',
                background_color=(0, 0, 0, 0)
            )
            main_text.bind(on_release=lambda x:self.say_hellow())
            self.textReference.append(main_text)
            Hint_text = Button(
                text="Food Menu",
                halign="left",
                font_size=mycard.width/6,
                bold=True,
                color=(206 / 255, 203 / 255, 203 / 255, 0.2),
                pos_hint={'center_x': 0.3, 'top': 0.8},
                size_hint=(1, None),
                height=mycard.height,
                background_normal='',
                background_color=(0, 0, 0, 0)
            )
            Hint_text.bind(on_release=lambda x:self.say_hellow())
            self.textReference.append(Hint_text)
            image.add_widget(imagebutton)
            mycard.add_widget(image)
            texture_part.add_widget(main_text)
            texture_part.add_widget(Hint_text)
            mycard.add_widget(texture_part)
            secondary_widget.add_widget(mycard)
        scrollbar.add_widget(secondary_widget)
        main_widget.add_widget(scrollbar)
        self.add_widget(main_widget)

    def adjust_sizes(self, mycard, new_size):
        new_font_size=0
        for i in range(0,len(self.textReference)):
            if i%2!=0:
                new_font_size = mycard.width / 15

            else:
                new_font_size=mycard.width/10
            self.textReference[i].font_size = new_font_size
            self.textReference[i].texture_size[1]=mycard.height/10
    def say_hellow(self):
        print("you Pressed the Button!!")



class SecondWin(Screen):
    pass
class MymdCard(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        Builder.load_file("md_card_py.kv")
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

        sm.add_widget(FirstWin(name='welcomeScreen'))
        sm.add_widget(SecondWin(name='functionScreen'))
        return sm




if __name__ == '__main__':
    MymdCard().run()
```

So for stability of the ScrollView I can't able to understand what will I do and even I don't know what kind of mistake I has do in this code.

Comment: Your post is missing the `md_card_py.kv` file.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Hello sir, in the md_card_py.kv file there is nothing in it. it is only have a template for the heading of the Hotel Name "Hotel Heera Panna and Family Restaurant"(Please see in Pictures) the Image of logo and the Name of the Hotel that's it in the file and nothing else. So for this reason I am not attaching that file  with my question.